# An error has occurred that has caused the transaction to be classified as an uncommittable transaction

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions, try-catch

`XACT_STATE()` can have 1, 0, -1 values. When it's 1, any action can be performed but when it's -1 only read or rollback can be performed. In which scenario a transaction is classified as uncommittable transaction.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms189797.aspx) is what msdn says.

> **The current request has an active user transaction, but an error has
>   occurred that has caused the transaction to be classified as an
>   uncommittable transaction**. The request cannot commit the transaction
>   or roll back to a savepoint; it can only request a full rollback of
>   the transaction. The request cannot perform any write operations until
>   it rolls back the transaction. The request can only perform read
>   operations until it rolls back the transaction. After the transaction
>   has been rolled back, the request can perform both read and write
>   operations and can begin a new transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2011/05/11/errors-raised-with-severity-level-16-may-cause-transactions-into-doomed-state.aspx):

**when your transaction is hitting Level 16 error the transaction may go into doomed state (XACT_STATE() =-1), though not always as explained above!!**

below are some examples given in blog:

```
--datatype conversion errors:

   DECLARE @GUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER 
   SELECT @GUID = CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 'ABC')  

---divide by zero errors:
   SELECT * FROM my_books WHERE Isbn/0 = 2

--dropping column which doesnt exists      
 ALTER TABLE my_books DROP COLUMN author;
```

The author also explains below about other error levels which may cause transaction to be doomed..

There could be lot more errors that may get the transactions into doomed state! The **user could refer to this blog as a reference to identify whether the error raised with severity\level 16 would roll back the transaction or not. If you wish you can also test errors with other severities or levels**

one more [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms164086.aspx) which will help in simulating each error level..